# Protection from cross-site-scripting Django Rest Framework

Tags: django, security, web, xss

I am creating API for forum web-site with DRF and want to protect it from XSS. For example if someone sends a request with a text included in html tags(button, form, script etc.) it is saved in database. I wan't to protect it somehow. I heard that I can do it through serailizer `escape` method or I can solve the problem on the middleware level by checking if there are any prohibited tags and if so, raise an error or just parse the row text from html and save it.

Also in some ednpoints I do really need to save data (including html) in the `TextField` , as I want my frontend client to be allowed to format text with HTML (basic markup), but in these case the idea of special middleware does not seem appropriate because it won't allow to send request with HTML text. Or I just should create a middleware to check if there are for example form or button tags and in this way raise error (if it is something like HTML lists, headlines, span tags don't raise error).

What solution works better? Or are there any other ways? Maybe it is up to frontend developer to work with it?
Thank you in advance.